# Draw multiple polygon on google maps API v3 javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have several coordinate data saved on my database. The data looked like this:

```
[
    [-8.411328650721382, 115.2549934387207],
    [-8.423385320191324, 115.26924133300781],
    [-8.428988996455418, 115.27507781982422],
    [-8.445120338164106, 115.2682113647461],
    [-8.452082077411186, 115.2656364440918],
    [-8.46430726648532, 115.26580810546875],
    [-8.470419715493609, 115.26615142822266],
    [-8.476022708444539, 115.26477813720703],
    [-8.481116267546547, 115.25671005249023],
    [-8.492491639030948, 115.24469375610352],
    [-8.481795403659492, 115.2414321899414],
    [-8.472287388879758, 115.24641036987305],
    [-8.462609346758175, 115.24606704711914],
    [-8.455308206642881, 115.24417877197266],
    [-8.445629737978635, 115.23714065551758],
    [-8.434252981999162, 115.2352523803711],
    [-8.422026840993878, 115.23490905761719],
    [-8.410479575344654, 115.23954391479492],
    [-8.405385084022475, 115.24383544921875]
]
```

I have to draw several polygon on map but when I do, all the polygons are connected each other.

Here is my javascript:

```
<script>

var map;
var i = 0;
var poly = {};
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -1.55038056899795, lng: 118.6962890625},
    zoom: 5,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });
  var jsonPeta = <?=$peta?>;
  var coordArray = [];
  var path = [];

  for(i=0;i<jsonPeta.length;i++){
    //console.log(i);
    coordArray = JSON.parse(jsonPeta[i].peta);
    coordArray.forEach(function(entry){
      path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(entry[0],entry[1]));
    });
    poly[i] = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: path,
    editable: false,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#03a9f4',
      clickable: true,
      fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  poly[i].setMap(map);
  console.log(poly[i]);
  }

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(input);

  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

if (places.length == 0) {
  return;
}

// Clear out the old markers.
markers.forEach(function(marker) {
  marker.setMap(null);
});
markers = [];

// For each place, get the icon, name and location.
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
places.forEach(function(place) {
  var icon = {
    url: place.icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
  };

  // Create a marker for each place.
  markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: icon,
    title: place.name,
    position: place.geometry.location
    //document.getElementById("lat").value = place.geometry.Latitude
  }));
  document.getElementById('lat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
  document.getElementById('lon').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    // Only geocodes have viewport.
    bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
  }
});
map.fitBounds(bounds);


});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do those coodrinates belong to one polygon or belong to many polygons?

Comment: it belongs to many polygon

Comment: I don't understand. How do you distinct them? You could achive yor goal if you would have devided groups of coords. Right now,  program doesn't know which is which and assume one array as one polygon. Which should be and is not incorrect at all. Problem is in your storing of coordinates. Try to store those in groups.

Comment: i already solved the problem mate, i just forgot to empty the array after add polygon on map :))

Comment: Ah, good. Happy coding. :)

Comment: can u please create a working demo for this question